# Can consumers act as producers and send messages to the message broker in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, distributed-system

Can we design pub-sub patterns in RabbitMQ where a consumer can also act as a producer and send messages to the message broker?

[pub-sub with the same service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9iQv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use producer API in consumer code? It should work...

You can find API docs for many languages in [Client Documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clients.html)

Regarding design, consumers may consume, do some processing and then produce - publish to some other exchange of the same or other messaging broker instance...

It's design decision...

Comment: Could you please give a link to the producer API? 
I cant seem to find it. It would be really helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the consumer can also act as a producer. It's a common use case that the consumer sends back a new message/task about something else once the first message has been processed.

Make sure that you separate the connections for the publisher and the consumer.
RabbitMQ can apply back pressure on the TCP connection when the publisher is sending too many messages for the server to handle. If you consume on the same TCP connection, the server might not receive the message acknowledgments from the client, thus effecting the consume performance. With a lower consume speed, the server will be overwhelmed.